# bootstrap row system clone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to clone the boostrap grid system on my own, but it seems I ran into a problem I can't solve:

This is my html:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">Card</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <div class="card card-rounded">
                    <div class="card-content">Card-rounded</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <div class="card card-noshadow">
                    <div class="card-content">Card-noshadow</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

An this is the css behind it:

```
.row {
margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

*[class^="col-"] {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.col-10 { width: 100% }
.col-9 { width: 90% }
.col-8 { width: 80% }
.col-7 { width: 70% }
.col-6 { width: 60% }
.col-5 { width: 50% }
.col-4 { width: 40% }
.col-3 { width: 30% }
.col-2 { width: 20% }
.col-1 { width: 10% }
```

These are global css settings:

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

I'm also using normalize.css.

The problem is, that the two `col-5` columns aren't displayed inline. Any help?

**EDIT**

Okay I got it:

I had to add a `float: left` to the 'col-'-classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your col-5 has a width of 50%, that is excluding the padding and optional borders etc. So 2 times 50% = 100% width + the width of the padding results in more width than you have.

You can add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include those properties in the width calculation.

**=== edited answer ===**

Box-sizing was used. You need to add a `float: left` to your cols.

Comment: Sorry for thath, can you share a link to example with full css?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the float on all `col` classes. I think this is what you are looking for.

```css
*[class^="col-"] {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    background-color: #f00;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-10 { width: 100% }
.col-9 { width: 90% }
.col-8 { width: 80% }
.col-7 { width: 70% }
.col-6 { width: 60% }
.col-5 { width: 50% }
.col-4 { width: 40% }
.col-3 { width: 30% }
.col-2 { width: 20% }
.col-1 { width: 10% }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">Card</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <div class="card card-rounded">
            <div class="card-content">Card-rounded</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
        <div class="card card-noshadow">
            <div class="card-content">Card-noshadow</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But to be honest, wouldn't it be a better idea to just build the grid from bootstrap source? Just get the git repo and use grunt to build the grid excluding all less files that are not relevant to the grid system. Take a look at the compiled css and you will find out, that there is a lot more to the bootstraps grid system than you thought.